# Display latest 5 posts on homepage

Tags: php

I'm currently using a custom made Twentytwelve child theme and would like to display the last 5 posts on the homepage using a shortcode. I have tried using the code below (added to `functions.php`) but to no avail - when I add the shortcode to the homepage, it doesn't display anything although as far as I can see, it should and I have a test post live.

```
function custom_prev_posts($limit = 5){
global $wpdb, $post;
$html = '';
$prev_posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_date < '%s' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT $limit", $post->post_date ) ); 

if($prev_posts){
$html .= '<ul>';
foreach ( $prev_posts as $prev_post  ) {
$html .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) . '">' .$prev_post->post_title . '</a></li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
}
return $html;
}

add_shortcode('last5', 'custom_prev_posts');
```

I'm thinking the issue may be related to the Twentytwelve theme. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or does anyone know of a working way to display the latest 5 posts inside a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `$limit` var, you can't set a default value like that because WordPress overwrites it with an empty value. Check out the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for the correct way to pass and set shortcode attributes.

```
function custom_prev_posts( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit' => 5
    ), $atts ) );
    // the rest of your code, $limit now works correctly
}
```

You can also now set a custom limit by adding limit to your shortcode: `[last5 limit=10]` Though last5 is an odd name for a shortcode that can display numbers of posts other than 5 :)

Also, for future reference, [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) so you can see errors your code is generating.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Also thanks for the links, very useful and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function custom_prev_posts($limit){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'limit' => 5,
    ), $atts ) );

    // check input paramters
    $limit = (int)$limit; // allow only numbers

    // output
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<ul>';
    $args = array('numberposts' => $limit);
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('last5', 'custom_prev_posts');
```

where I use `wp_get_recent_posts()`, you can read more about it in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

**Edit:**
You should definitely check out the link to the shortcode api provided by @Milo